# How to insert images into the database and fetch it from the database and display using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, file-upload

How do I insert images into the database, and fetch it from the database and display using PHP?

I have tried many times as i am a beginner of php please help me out.

Comment: Are you sure you wan't store image in database?? Isn't better to store only path of image?

Comment: Mihran, if you host your website at a cheap host, you won't get apache (or IIS) to have write privileges. You will have to store uploads in a database.

Comment: Databases are best kept to just holding data. Yes, an image can be considered data, but it is normally better kept as a file and, as @Mihran suggests, you store the reference to that file in the database rather than the whole file's contents.

Comment: @nash Sounds like a crap host.

Comment: nash, I suggest changing host in that case. There's lot of competition in the web hosting market and no reason to stay with some crap host. You can adapt yourself to small problems, but not allowing file writes is not a "small" problem.

Comment: Almost every host provides write privileges, if one doesn't, you shouldn't be hosting with them. Did you get control panel access?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a BLOB field for storing binary data, but please be aware that the performance may be moderate. It's almost always better to store the image as a file on disk and just store the file name in the database. To fetch the image from db, you will need to read the whole image into memory, which is a waste of resources. It's better to offload the image handling to the web server which can stream the image to the client.

Answer (score 2):

As much as this is not a recommended practice, if you have your heart set on doing this, there are a pile of tutorials online which will walk you through how to do this:

- [Uploading Files To MySQL Database](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx)
- [Upload a File and write to MySQL](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql.htm%20Upload%20a%20File%20and%20write%20to%20MySQL)
- [Upload Files to MySQL using PHP Tutorial](http://www.techtoolblog.com/archives/upload-files-to-mysql-using-php-tutorial)
- [Uploading files into a MySQL database using PHP](http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: I realized storing the path name is better than storing an image in a database. Any ways thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `image` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `filename` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `mime_string` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `data` longblob NOT NULL,
    `data_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `hash` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `compressed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    `remote_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `image_I_1` (`hash`),
    KEY `image_I_2` (`remote_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=125 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

When you write the file back to the output, you'll have to write the HTTP header content type
to the same as the mime type:

```
header( 'Content-type', 'image/png' );
```

Which is why you store the mime type along with it.